# What is the problem with my lemon tree?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, citrus

I got a lemon tree 3 months ago, and moved it to a bigger pot (outdoors) and applied fertilizer.
Within a month, it lost all the leaves (while still green).
Since then, many new leaves appeared (lighter in color and has no spots) and drop within couple of weeks. I noticed leaves with few spots as shown in the photo.
I live in a very hot area where the temperature now reaches 45°C. I moved the plant into a relatively shady place where it gets about 3 hours of sun.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: The common causes are temperatures too low in winter, and over watering. The first one option doesn't apply to your question! Lemons grow in dry climates, they don't need lots of water just because the weather is hot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Currently I water it every 3-4 days based on how dry the soil seems to be..I'll reduce the watering frequency and see if it works.. What about the curling leaves, the small yellow spots and the dry parts of the leaves .. Is it related to overwatering or could be some infection or nutrients deficiency?

Comment: Lemon tree likes acid soil. Overwatering (on hard water zone) will reduce acidity, and so the plant have more difficult to absorb nutrients. Did you use a fertilizer specific for citrus? But I would look carefully trunk, branches and leaves, to see if there are also insects of diseases.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi , Thanks for your reply.. I've checked it carefully, no insects at all. I've checked the soil pH, it's 6.5 .. I've used a 5-10-5 npk fertilizer, not specific for citrus trees